# Google Play Services for Cloud based apps?

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth, google-play-services

I want to avoid using WebViews to get OAuth tokens from Google. (Asking user to share his contacts, profile info etc). I used the **Google Play Services APIs** for that.

Since my app is cloud based (logic happens in cloud), I have to save these tokens in the cloud. I also have to let user sign in from multiple devices (without asking him Google permissions every time he logs in from a new device)

I tried to implement the technique mentioned in this [Google blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html).

I tried hands on with the method mentioned in the blog. It did not work exactly as I wished. I also checked +Tim Bray's Google Code project (favcolor-accountchooser) and it had the following code.

```
        try {
            // if this works, token is guaranteed to be usable
            token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(FavColorMain.this, mEmail, SCOPE);

        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
            startActivityForResult(userAuthEx.getIntent(), AUTHUTIL_REQUEST_CODE);
            token = null;

        }
```

It conflicts the concept mentioned in the blog. The 'token string' obtained is not sent back to the server and in the exception block, further permissions (scopes) are asked from the user. What does this snippet imply?

Also, what is the role of the 'web app' all along? I don't see it being of any use other than being mentioned in the scope parameter.

Another major issue

For example
My app takes contacts permission from multiple Google IDs and then merges duplicates and gives a unified contacts list. Now, all the magic happens in the servers and the servers are the ones who need the tokens.

My Android app uses the Google Play services APIs and gets user permissions for multiple Google Accounts (to read contacts). How do I pass there tokens to my web app ( just through a https connection?). Can't the web app under the same project get these tokens once the user grants permission for the Android app (under the same project)?.

If now I install the same app on another Android phone, I have to again ask the user to give me permission for accessing contacts for each of the accounts, (even though he has given me permission before), since there is no actual concept of 'login' here. All the tokens has to be sent from the mobile to the server.

Alternative: I have to use the Web View and directly get the tokens for the cloud apps, instead of using Google Play Services SDK, which is counter intuitive. (In our +Friday app, maximum user drop outs happen on the web view screen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if you look closely, the token value is passed to mCustomer.execute(), which for example in Fetcher.java, packs it up in some JSON and sends it off to the back-end with a POST.  The “Web app” should be the registered client ID of the back-end you’re going to send the ID Token to.

Yes, you can pass the tokens to your web app and use them on the back end. Remember to use HTTPS whenever you’re doing this kind of thing.

We’re working on making the approval stickier, so that if you get it for a particular user/scope combination on one Android, it should work on others too.  See https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/CrossClientAuth

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. But one small doubt on the link you shared.  -The section "Cross-client Access Tokens" mentions that multiple client IDs (Android, Web) etc under a same project will have tokens authorized by either of them.
-"Android app obtains offline access for Web back-end" Again mentions about  method to send over the authorization code (to the web backend). But according to the other section, we needn't send this code, the web should already share the consent user has given?